# Is there a 2.5 mile diameter object crawling along the Pacific floor?

Tags: oceanography

[Sputnik News reported in 2017](https://sputniknews.com/art_living/201703031051214932-mystery-object-pacific-ocean-found/)

> An unusual object of surprising size was spotted potentially crawling
> across the floor of the Pacific Ocean, some 3,000 feet below the
> surface. The object has a 2.5-mile diameter and some have speculated
> that it seems artificial.
>
> The object has apparently left a 41-mile track behind it, as it rolls along the seabed, offshore of the California coast. The tracks almost resemble those left by tank treads.
>
> The object was found on Google Maps by alien hunting and conspiracy-theory group SecureTeam10. "As you're seeing here, we have some very strange lines that almost look like a large vehicle was moving on the bottom of the ocean," said SecureTeam10 member Tyler in a Youtube video.

The article goes on to quote commenters dismissing the claim.

Was a large 2.5 mi (4km) wide object found moving on the floor of the Pacific ocean?

Comment: The article makes it very obvious that there was no **object** found, only patterns in elevation data that can be interpreted as — but that have not been positively identified as — "tracks". So — still — no, there has not been any 2.5 mile wide **object** found. Also I claim that "Sputnik News" is not notable.

Comment: This was also reported on by the [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-4276248/UFOlogists-claim-crawling-circle-seafloor.html). Despite their reputation, they are a notable source, so the claim is notable.

Comment: Boy, talk about your fake news!!  The track is only 2.3 miles wide!

Answer (score 32):

The article does not identify the precise location, but there are plenty of apparent subsea tracks resembling those left by tank treads easily identifiable on Google maps.  To take an arbitrary example with round co-ordinates, try [35N, 132W](https://www.google.com/maps/@35,-132,500000m/data=!3m1!1e3) between California and Hawaii

These are artefacts cause by high resolution scanning by ships (so typically linear following the ship's course) superimposed on wider low resolution scans using other methods

[Google blogged about this in 2009](https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/02/atlantis-no-it-atlant-isnt.html), saying that Atlantis had not been discovered in a case where the tracks appeared to have a particularly regular pattern

*Added:*  It seems that the *mystery object* in the claim may be near [50N, 140W](https://www.google.com/maps/@50,-140,200000m/data=!3m1!1e3) and the image can be [zoomed-in](https://www.google.com/maps/@50,-140,20000m/data=!3m1!1e3) without being any more persuasive, especially if you contrast it with the [Badlands Guardian in Alberta](https://www.google.com/maps/@50.0104123,-110.1129438,1000m/data=!3m1!1e3)

Comment: So people looking for stuff left tracks that looked like evidence for stuff. How ... delicious that is.

Comment: No, the tracking _does not affect_ the ocean floor. The difference is caused when combining high and low resolution maps. This is a common resampling issue in computer graphics.

Comment: @Dúthomhas - I do not know who you are saying "No" to, as neither I nor RedSonja disagree with you

Comment: @Henry, I am responding to RedSonja's phrasing that suggests that scanning ships are leaving something behind, that is, changing the ocean floor. The intent was to clarify that the tracks are not physical, but in the maps.